# Strange behaviour of asp.net button on Firefox of pressing twice

Tags: asp.net, firefox

If I have this asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Save" Width="150px" OnClick="Button_Save_Click" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

In order to prevent the user to press the button twice to insert two data records, I added this in the code behind:

```
Button_Save.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled='true';" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button_Save_Data, null) + ";");
```

It works fine with IE and Chrome. However, in Firefox, every time the user presses the button once, I got two data records inserted.

After some time googling, I modified the button this way by adding: `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Save" Width="150px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button_Save_Click" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

Then it also works with Firefox, only one data record inserted. But then I will have to add that setting for every button on my web application. It requires a lot of work.

However, I think this is really a big problem if that is the case always with asp.net app running on Firefox. Or did I implement something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for UseSubmitBehavior="false" . Fixed my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off adding checks to your SAVE code to prevent duplicate POSTs. I've used code like yours and still had duplicate records because someone hit the Refresh button at the wrong time.

**EDIT**: 
Here is the code I use. Key is to match a value on the server with a value coming back in the postback.

In Page_Load:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Session("rcdupdate") = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString)
End If
```

In Page_Prerender

```
ViewState("rcdupdate") = Session("rcdupdate")
```

And in the Save routine

```
If Session("rcdupdate").ToString = ViewState("rcdupdate").ToString Then
   ... write the data to the database ...
   Session("rcdupdate") = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `asp:button` and add your new functionality, then fine/replace all of your `asp:buttons`.  Going forward you can then change all your buttons in once place.

Comment: this is not an ideal solution I think because it is strange to be a problem with firefox